# does Angularjs change detection affect angular change detection

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-hybrid

i went through some articles, it says if you want to improve the performance you can set the ngZone to noop.

My application is hybrid (angular and angularjs combination), does anybody know if changes done in angularjs component also triggers the change detection in Angular.

how to improve the performance of hybrid application

Comment: well I know if you're making your own angular 2 application it has imported zone.js unless you specify otherwise. In that scenario, you may have 2 change detections. 1 for angularJS and 1 for Angular

Comment: but does the change detection in angularjs element, for e.g setTimeOut in angularjs will trigger change detection in Angular